# Set-MsolCompanySettings equivalent for Graph API or AzureAD cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure

Within the MSOnline module, there is a `Set-MsolCompanySettings` cmdlet to disable user browsing within an AAD:

```
Set-MsolCompanySettings -UsersPermissionToReadOtherUsersEnabled $false
```

I wan't to set this setting within an AAD in MCD (Microsoft Cloud Deutschland - Azure Germany). Unfortunately, I don't found a way to connect to an AAD MCD using MSOL - did I missed something?

Anyhow, I can use the Graph API and probably the AzureAD module to set this flag but I didn't find any related resources / cmdlets. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Connect-MsolService -AzureEnvironment AzureGermanyCloud
```

If you will see error saying that AzureEnvironment is not recognized parameter then make sure to install AdministrationConfig-V1.1.166.0-GA.msi from http://connect.microsoft.com/site1164/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=59185